# UTF-8 in batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Got script that send email notification if something was created or modified. Got a small problem, script doesn't recognize these letters: ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪąčęėįšųū

Tried: `chcp 65001`

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "emailUserName=foo@bar.com"
set "emailPassword=lol"
set "target=foo@bar.com"
set "subject=ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪ("
FOR %%G IN (*) DO attrib -A "%%G"
:loop
set "body="
FOR %%G IN (*) DO (
attrib "%%G" | findstr /B /L A 1>nul
if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
    echo "%%G"
    set "body=!body!^<br ^/^>%%G"
    attrib -A "%%G"
    )
) 2>nul
if not "%body%"=="" echo sending email
if not "%body%"=="" set "body=Buvo ikelta nuotrauka:!body!"
if not "%body%"=="" powershell.exe -command "Send-MailMessage -From 
'!emailUserName!' -to '!target!' -Subject '!subject!' -Body '!body!' - 
BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer 'smtp.gmail.com' -port '587' -UseSsl -Credential (New- 
Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 
('!emailUserName!', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String '!emailPassword!' - 
AsPlainText -Force)))"
goto :loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cmds are ANSI, not unicode.

So the supported chars depend on the codepage configured in your computer.

Either the chars you are trying to use are hard coded in your script and you just have to save the script in ansi or it comes from an input to the script and then you'd better use something else like vbs or powershell.